# Maven retrieves a non working jar

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jar

I'm using maven to download jedis-2.6.2 jar. But when maven downloads the jar it has no content and can't be unarchived. When i download the jar by clicking 'Download jar' at http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/redis.clients/jedis/2.6.2 - the downloaded jar is working fine. How can i set up maven to download the correct jar?

Below is an image so you can see that the redis.client.jedis jar is downloaded empty.

[image: Here you can see that the redis.client.jedis jar is empty.]

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml or a tleast dependency section of it

Comment: pom.xml would help - i just used the dependencie under http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/redis.clients/jedis/2.6.2 and it all worked fine for me.

Comment: this dependency was working fine `<dependency>
      <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
      <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>`

Comment: you might have a corrupted file part in your .m2 repo.  Delete that redis directory and try mvn install it again

Comment: djb's comment did the trick, guess i somehow had a corrupted file in .m2. Thanks and pls post an answer to mark as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is with the corrupted files in your .m2 repository. It can be resolved in 2 ways.

First way is to delete that particular(redis in your case) folder or file and do a maven install again. You can find those folders in the following (default)path : in windows `Documents and Settings\your username\.m2` or `$home/.m2` folder on Ubuntu(Linux).

Second way is to `purge-local-repository` using maven itself, this will eliminate the manual process of deleting if and when this issue occurs. You can give multiple flags and you can see how to use it in the documentation. It will remove the dependencies of the project from the cache.